# Modules installation for Python3.3

Tags: python

I'm trying to install the biopython module on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine (64x). I first upgraded to Python3.3 by installing from source (biopython does not support other versions), that seems ok.

However, I installed some modules using the `sudo apt-get install python-module` command but I can't call them from a python shell:

```
dovah@AsusX501A:~$ python3.3
Python 3.3.5 (default, Mar 12 2014, 02:09:17)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from biopython import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'biopython'
>>> from Bio import * ##as suggested in http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/module-tree.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'Bio'
```

As you can see, the modules are installed:

```
dovah@AsusX501A:~$ sudo apt-get install python-biopython
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
python-biopython is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And so is biopython (quite strange though: line 14 says `biopython-1.64-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg` so best hit was found for version 2.7, not 3.3):

```
dovah@AsusX501A:~$ sudo easy_install -f http://biopython.org/DIST/ biopython
Searching for biopython
Reading http://biopython.org/DIST/
Best match: biopython 1.64
Downloading http://biopython.org/DIST/biopython-1.64.zip
Processing biopython-1.64.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-v5LJZz/biopython-1.64/setup.cfg
Running biopython-1.64/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-v5LJZz/biopython-1.64/egg-dist-tmp-TruGJH
warning: no previously-included files matching '.cvsignore' found under directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory '*'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Bio.Entrez.Parser: module references __path__
Adding biopython 1.64 to easy-install.pth file
Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/biopython-1.64-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for biopython
Finished processing dependencies for biopython
```

Are modules specific for a given Python version? Is the system still stuck on Python 2.7?
Obviousely I can't simply remove 2.7 unless I want to mess up my whole OS.

Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT**
numpy successfully installed using: `sudo apt-get install python3-numpy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works perfectly, check it out.
First command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Second command:

```
pip3 install biopython
```

```
root@saurabh-ubuntu:/home/saurabh# apt-get install python-pip python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libexpat1-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.4-dev python-colorama python-distlib
  python-html5lib python-requests python-setuptools python-urllib3
  python3-colorama python3-dev python3-distlib python3-html5lib
  python3-setuptools python3.4-dev
Suggested packages:
  python-genshi
Recommended packages:
  python-dev-all
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libexpat1-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.4-dev python-colorama python-distlib
  python-html5lib python-pip python-requests python-setuptools python-urllib3
  python3-colorama python3-dev python3-distlib python3-html5lib python3-pip
  python3-setuptools python3.4-dev
0 upgraded, 17 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 48.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/main libexpat1-dev amd64 2.1.0-4ubuntu1 [115 kB]
Get:2 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/main libpython3.4-dev amd64 3.4.0-2ubuntu1 [27.0 MB]
Get:3 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/main libpython3-dev amd64 3.4.0-0ubuntu2 [7,002 B]
Get:4 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/universe python-colorama all 0.2.5-0.1ubuntu1 [18.3 kB]
Get:5 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/universe python-distlib all 0.1.8-1 [113 kB]
Get:6 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/main python-html5lib all 0.999-2 [83.2 kB]
Get:7 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/main python-setuptools all 3.3-1ubuntu1 [230 kB]
Get:8 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/main python-urllib3 all 1.7.1-1build1 [38.9 kB]
Get:9 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/main python-requests all 2.2.1-1 [42.5 kB]
Get:10 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/universe python-pip all 1.5.4-1 [97.7 kB]
Get:11 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/universe python3-colorama all 0.2.5-0.1ubuntu1 [11.9 kB]
Get:12 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/main python3.4-dev amd64 3.4.0-2ubuntu1 [425 kB]
Get:13 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/main python3-dev amd64 3.4.0-0ubuntu2 [1,192 B]
Get:14 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/universe python3-distlib all 0.1.8-1 [113 kB]
Get:15 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/universe python3-html5lib all 0.999-2 [79.3 kB]
Get:16 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/main python3-setuptools all 3.3-1ubuntu1 [144 kB]
Get:17 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ trusty/universe python3-pip all 1.5.4-1 [80.4 kB]
Fetched 28.6 MB in 2min 18s (207 kB/s)                                         
Selecting previously unselected package libexpat1-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 260300 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libexpat1-dev_2.1.0-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libexpat1-dev:amd64 (2.1.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython3.4-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.4-dev_3.4.0-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.4-dev:amd64 (3.4.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython3-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3-dev_3.4.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3-dev:amd64 (3.4.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-colorama.
Preparing to unpack .../python-colorama_0.2.5-0.1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-colorama (0.2.5-0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-distlib.
Preparing to unpack .../python-distlib_0.1.8-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-distlib (0.1.8-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-html5lib.
Preparing to unpack .../python-html5lib_0.999-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-html5lib (0.999-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-setuptools.
Preparing to unpack .../python-setuptools_3.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-setuptools (3.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-urllib3.
Preparing to unpack .../python-urllib3_1.7.1-1build1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-urllib3 (1.7.1-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-requests.
Preparing to unpack .../python-requests_2.2.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-requests (2.2.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pip.
Preparing to unpack .../python-pip_1.5.4-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-pip (1.5.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-colorama.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-colorama_0.2.5-0.1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-colorama (0.2.5-0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3.4-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../python3.4-dev_3.4.0-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.4-dev (3.4.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-dev_3.4.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-dev (3.4.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-distlib.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-distlib_0.1.8-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-distlib (0.1.8-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-html5lib.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-html5lib_0.999-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-html5lib (0.999-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-setuptools.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-setuptools_3.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-setuptools (3.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-pip.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-pip_1.5.4-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pip (1.5.4-1) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.5) ...
Processing 1 added doc-base file...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up libexpat1-dev:amd64 (2.1.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libpython3.4-dev:amd64 (3.4.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libpython3-dev:amd64 (3.4.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up python-colorama (0.2.5-0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python-distlib (0.1.8-1) ...
Setting up python-html5lib (0.999-2) ...
Setting up python-setuptools (3.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python-urllib3 (1.7.1-1build1) ...
Setting up python-requests (2.2.1-1) ...
Setting up python-pip (1.5.4-1) ...
Setting up python3-colorama (0.2.5-0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3.4-dev (3.4.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-dev (3.4.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up python3-distlib (0.1.8-1) ...
Setting up python3-html5lib (0.999-2) ...
Setting up python3-setuptools (3.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-pip (1.5.4-1) ...
root@saurabh-ubuntu:/home/saurabh# pip3 install biopython
Downloading/unpacking biopython
  Downloading biopython-1.64.tar.gz (11.7MB): 11.7MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/biopython/setup.py) egg_info for package biopython

    warning: no previously-included files matching '.cvsignore' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory '*'
Installing collected packages: biopython
  Running setup.py install for biopython
    building 'Bio.cpairwise2' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c Bio/cpairwise2module.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/Bio/cpairwise2module.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/Bio/cpairwise2module.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/Bio/cpairwise2.cpython-34m.so
    building 'Bio.trie' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -IBio -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c Bio/triemodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/Bio/triemodule.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -IBio -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c Bio/trie.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/Bio/trie.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/Bio/triemodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/Bio/trie.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/Bio/trie.cpython-34m.so
    building 'Bio.Nexus.cnexus' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c Bio/Nexus/cnexus.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/Bio/Nexus/cnexus.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/Bio/Nexus/cnexus.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/Bio/Nexus/cnexus.cpython-34m.so

    warning: no previously-included files matching '.cvsignore' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory '*'
Successfully installed biopython
Cleaning up...
root@saurabh-ubuntu:/home/saurabh# python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Bio
>>> 
[3]+  Stopped                 python3
root@saurabh-ubuntu:/home/saurabh#
```

Comment: pip successfully downloaded, executed and installed. However, I get `sudo: pip-3.3: command not found` for the biopython installation.

Comment: then try sudo pip3 install biopython

Comment: I get errors. Please refer to my comments on @Salem's answers to this question.

Comment: The name of the module is Bio. So use `import Bio`

Comment: As you can see in my posted question, Bio isn't recognized as module under python3.3. And it isn't configured for python3.2, which I installed from Synaptic. I had to upgrade, so I installed version 3.3 from source because Synaptic doesn't include it. So maybe this is the main problem. In fact, `/usr/bin/python3` gives me back python3.2 by default. Any ideas for fixing this?

Comment: Install it from apt then [link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3.3&searchon=names) `sudo apt-get install python3.3` First make sure in your sources.list the release is one of the versions in the link I gave you (or stable) because 12.04 is unsupported now.

Comment: Yes, it works for Python 2.7 but my codes are in 3.x language... Would be a shame if I couldn't import my scripts.

Comment: Try installing python with apt.

Comment: It worked for me. It's probably like you said, maybe the problem exists because something went wrong with the python installation. Use apt-get. There is a python3 [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=names&keywords=python3) for Presise. `sudo apt-get install python3`. Then follow the commands I've given in my answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Usually `python-*` packages are targeted to Python 2.X. The ones to Python 3 are named `python3-*`.

In your case the package you need is not available, so you will need to install it "manually".

This can be easily achieved with the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install biopython
```

If you dont want it to be installed system-wide you can use a virtualenv:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3.3 some_location  # replace 3.3 with your version. 
$ source some_location/bin/activate
$ pip install biopython # python3-dev should be already installed.
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but on sudo pip3 install biopython I get the following error: `Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/biopython
Storing debug log for failure in /home/dovah/.pip/pip.log`. It seems not detecting my installed version 3.3

Comment: Other remark: my system is running on 12.04LTS, so I had to `sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools` & `sudo easy_install3 pip3` (`python3-pip` isn't available for distros before 13.04)

Comment: Can you post the output in `~/.pip/pip.log`?

Comment: Actually, `bash: cd: /home/dovah/.pip/pip.log: Not a directory`

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was the contents of the file: `cat ~/.pip/pip.log`.

Comment: Here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zv02fgr3wns8fks/Untitled (sorry, it was too long to post it here)

Comment: `Biopython requires Python 3.3 or later (or Python 2.6 or 2.7). Python 3.2 detected` indeed it is using 3.2 instead of your version. Try to replace the symlink: `sudo mv /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3_backup` and then `sudo ln -s PATH/TO/PYTHON3.3 /usr/bin/python3`. You can find the path to python3.3 using `which python3.3`. NOTE: this may break something, so the virtualenv option is prefered.

Comment: Just a detail. What do you mean by `# replace 3.3 with your version.` ?

Comment: In your case probably nothing (you may need to specify the full path to python3.3 if virtualenv does not find it). I just added it so if anyone comes with a similar problem knows that has to change that bit.